# How can I negate the exit code of a command used in ExecCondition of a systemd service

Tags: linux, shell, systemd

I would like to negate the exit code of a command used in ExecCondition of a systemd service. However, I cannot use a "!" before the command, because this character is used by systemd for something slightly else (proceed, even if command fails [1]).

```
[Unit]
Description=Negated Exec Condition

[Service]
Type=oneshot

ExecCondition=/usr/bin/command # How can I negate the exit code?

ExecStart=...

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

[1] https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: I already tried 'ExecCondition=(! /usr/bin/command)', which results in 'Failed at step EXEC spawning (!: No such file or directory'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the shell.

```
ExecCondition=/bin/sh -c '! "$@"' -- /usr/bin/command
```

Comment: Okay, looks good. What about: ExecCondition=/bin/sh -c '! /usr/bin/command'?

Comment: what about it? then command will be subject to shell quoting, except for that it's the same. `/bin/sh -c '! "$@"' --` is a nice prefix.